# One thread for many tasks vs many threads for each task. Do sleeping threads aftect the performance of the server?

Tags: multithreading, celery, production-environment

a) I have a task which I want the server to do every X hours for every user (~5000 users). Is it better to:

1 - Create a worker thread for each user that does the task and sleep for X hours then start again, where each task is running in random time (so that most tasks are sleeping at every moment)

2 - Create one Thread that loops through the users and do the task for each user then start again (even if this takes more than X hours).

b) if plan 1 is used, do sleeping threads aftect the performance of the server?
c) If the answer is yes, do the sleeping thread have the same effect as the thread that is doing the task?

Note that this server is not only used for this task. It is used for all the communications with the ~5000 clients.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough details about your issue for a complete answer. However, based on the information you provided, I would:

- create a timer (threading.timer)
- set an interval which will be the time interval between processing a "batch" of 5'000 users

Then say the method/task you want to perform is called UpdateUsers:
when timer "ticks", **in** the UpdateUsers method (callback):
 1. stop timer 
 2. loop and perform task for each user 3. start timer

This way you ensure that the task is performed for each user and there is no overlapping if it takes more than X hours total. The updates will happen every Y time, where Y is the time interval you set for your timer. Also, this uses maximum one thread, depending on how your server/service is coded.

Comment: Stopping a timer does not ensure that the callback can be invoked in the future. Arbitrarily many callbacks can be queued already.

Comment: I meant stop the timer inside the callback method (edited). I don't understand what is incorrect?

Comment: After you have stopped the timer the callback can still be invoked. Timer does not protect from concurrent invocations of the callback.

Comment: Ok I understand. But say you have this timer and callback in a class; service instantiates one class, and timer starts in the constructor (or StartTimer() method, does not matter). Only one instance, one timer, one thread calling the method at a time. Why would concurrent access be an issue/risk?

Comment: Timer events are posted to the thread-pool. Not one thread but arbitrarily many. Most code is not safe if invoked concurrently. I agree with most of your answer. I just wanted to point out this one detail.

Comment: I was asking because I implemented this on a server I developed and is running ok in production. But if there is a risk I didn't see, I will need to fix it, maybe with a lock/monitor/semaphore (?). Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: consider using Monitor.TryEnter with zero timeout. That way you can make sure that only one timer tick runs at the same time. Should a second once come in it is dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Sleeping threads generally do not affect CPU usage. They consume 1MB of stack memory each. This is not a big deal for dozens of threads. It is a big deal for 5000 threads.

Have one thread or timer dedicated to triggering the hourly work. Once per hour you can process the users. You can use parallelism if you want. Process the users using `Parallel.ForEach` or any other technique you like.

Whether you choose a thread or timer doesn't matter for CPU usage in any meaningful way. Do what fits your use app most.